# How to import data to another model in Angular?

Tags: angular

I'm new to Angular and have some burning questions. As I am not experienced in this language, I hope you all may understand what I'm asking.

I have looked through the books and other sources but can't seem to get the right answer

In my user.ts I declare the User class

```
export class User {
  constructor(public id:number, public name: string, public image: string, public hobbies: any ) {}
}
```

In my hobbies.ts I declare the Hobbies class

```
export class Hobby {
  constructor(public id:number, public hobbyType:string, public hobbyDesc:string) {}
}
```

I had a list of Hobbies in hobby-list.ts

```
export const HOBBIES: Hobby[] = [{id:1, hobbyType:"Snorkeling", hobbyDesc:"Snorkeling is the practice of swimming on or through a body of water while equipped with a diving mask, a shaped breathing tube called a snorkel, and usually swimfins. In cooler waters, a wetsuit may also be worn."},
{id:2, hobbyType:"Diving", hobbyDesc:"Scuba diving is a mode of underwater diving where the diver uses a self-contained underwater breathing apparatus, which is completely independent of surface supply, to breathe underwater."}
]
```

I listed an array of User in another ts

```
import {Hobby} from './hobby.ts';
import {HOBBIES} from './hobby-list.ts';
export const USERS: User[] = [{id:1, name:"Mandy",image:"mandy.jpg",hobbies: <not sure how to get the hobby type listing from Hobbies-list.ts>}
]
```

So the expected results will be having the list of Users display in User.componment.html and the user's hobbies will be shown 
Eg. 
Name: Mandy `<br>`
Image: mandy.jpg `<br>`
Hobbies: Scuba Diving

I reckon the html code will be like this?

```
<h2>All Users</h2>
<ul *ngFor="let user of users">
<li>{{user.name}}</li>
<ul *ngFor="let hob of users.hobby">
<li>{{hob.hobbyType}}</li>
</ul>
</ul>
```

Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

I think you are asking how to  set hobbies property in const USERS. Then first you change the User Class hobbies property type to array of Hobby as shown below :

```
export class User {
  constructor(public id:number, public name: string, public image: string, public hobbies: Hobby[] ) {}
}
```

Then you can assign  hobbies property in const USERS as follows

```
import {Hobby} from './hobby.ts';
import {HOBBIES} from './hobby-list.ts';
export const USERS: User[] = [{id:1, name:"Mandy",image:"mandy.jpg",hobbies:HOBBIES }
]
```

In component class file assign

```
this.users =USERS // assign the USER constant
```

In HTML

```
<div *ngFor="let user of users">
  {{user.name}} <br/>
   <img [src]="user.image"/> <br/>
   Hobbies 
   <ul *ngFor="let hob of users.hobby">
     <li>{{hob.hobbyType}}</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

To  assign some specific hobbies to users.Create  class variable.

```
hobbies :  Hobby[] =HOBBIES ;
```

Now assign  USER

```
export const USERS: User[] = [
{id:1, name:"Mandy",image:"mandy.jpg",hobbies:[this.hobbies[0] ] },
{id:1, name:"Mandy",image:"mandy.jpg",hobbies:[this.hobbies[0],this.hobbies[1] ] }
]
```

or you can assign HOBBIES  as follows

```
    import {Hobby} from './hobby.ts';
    import {HOBBIES} from './hobby-list.ts';
    export const USERS: User[] = [{id:1, name:"Mandy",image:"mandy.jpg",hobbies:[HOBBIES[0]] },
{id:2, name:"Mandy1",image:"mandy1.jpg",hobbies:[HOBBIES[0],HOBBIES[0]] }

    ]
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! I managed to have all of the hobbiesType appearing. But now all the hobbiesType are showing on each user. But this is not the result I need as I need to show eg. User ID: #1, HobbyType: Diving; User ID:  #2, HobbyType: Swimming; User ID:  #3, HobbyType: Yoga, Swimming and etcs. How can I improvise the code from here?

Comment: Hey for that you to  you have reorganize your USER data

Comment: Hi Debabrata Paul Chowdhury , thanks for the reply. Would you kindly guide me on this? As Im still new in Aungular. Thank you.

Comment: I have edited answer please try this .If you need have help  please tell

Comment: Hi. I have added `code hobbies :  Hobby[] =HOBBIES ; to User component  And assign `code hobbies:[this.hobbies[0] ] to User-list. But there is an error showing up as " Cannot read property 'hobbies' of undefined"

Comment: Are the both userlist  and hobbies : Hobby[] =HOBBIES ;  on same page?

Comment: I have edited code `export const USERS: User[] = [{id:1, name:"Mandy",image:"mandy.jpg",hobbies:[HOBBIES[0]] },
{id:2, name:"Mandy1",image:"mandy1.jpg",hobbies:[HOBBIES[0],HOBBIES[0]] }
] `  Please try this

Answer (score 0):

the proble is your import, you do destructuring or use `export default` in your models for example: `export default class User {}`,
but with only export you need apply destructuring like this:

```js
import {Hobby} from './hobby.ts';
import {HOBBIES} from './hobby-list.ts';
export const USERS: User[] = [{id:1, name:"Mandy",image:"mandy.jpg",hobbies: <not sure how to get the hobby type listing from Hobbies-list.ts>}
]
```

Comment: I do not get your comment. Do you mean I have to change the code from `code` export class User to `code` export default class User {} ?

Comment: No, you hace two ways to impot if you use export default you can import directly without use “{}” el se of only use export you need use “{}” to import, you can read about in this link https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html

Comment: Oh I re-looked at my code.. It is typo from my side. My code are originally : `code` import {Hobby} from './hobby.ts';
`code` import {HOBBIES} from './hobby-list.ts'; I forgot the {} when I wrote the code here. What I need help was getting hobbyType from the {hobby} class to be shown on {User}. Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0):

```
 export class Hobby {

     id:number;
     hobbyType:string;
     hobbyDesc:string

    }



export class User {

id:number;
name: string; 
image: string;

hobby: Hobby

}


export class Users {

 user: User [];


}
```

> In Template

```
<h2>All Users</h2>
<ul *ngFor="let user of users">
  <li>{{user.name}}</li>
<ul *ngFor="let hob of user.hobby">
 <li>{{hob.hobbyType}}</li>
```

Comment: It's better to provide some explanation to the answer

Comment: Hi Raju, thanks for the help! Now all of the hobbiesType are showing on each users. But this is not the result I need as I need to show eg. User ID: #1, HobbyType: Diving; User ID:  #2, HobbyType: Swimming; User ID:  #3, HobbyType: Yoga, Swimming and etcs. How can I improvise the code from here?